# Customize equality with scalatest

Tags: scala, scalatest

I wanted to make a very simple example demonstrating how to customized equality when using the equal matcher for a number:

```
(29.0001) should equal (29.0) (+-0.0002)
```

I know you can use a range check directly for this kind of thing but this is what I wanted to show. Open to some other suggestion for showing a simple one liner for customizing equality.

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

Extract from [the documentation](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_matchers#usingCustomMatchers) :

One good way to organize custom matchers is to place them inside one or more traits that you can then mix into the suites that need them. Here's an example:

```
import org.scalatest._
import matchers._

trait CustomMatchers {

  class FileEndsWithExtensionMatcher(expectedExtension: String) extends Matcher[java.io.File] {

    def apply(left: java.io.File) = {
      val name = left.getName
      MatchResult(
        name.endsWith(expectedExtension),
        s"""File $name did not end with extension "$expectedExtension"""",
        s"""File $name ended with extension "$expectedExtension""""
      )
    }
  }

  def endWithExtension(expectedExtension: String) = new FileEndsWithExtensionMatcher(expectedExtension)
}

// Make them easy to import with:
// import CustomMatchers._
object CustomMatchers extends CustomMatchers
```

You can then write

```
import org.scalatest._
import Matchers._
import java.io.File
import CustomMatchers._

new File("essay.text") should endWithExtension ("txt")
```

Answer (score 0):

Scalacheck's matchers are not that good.
You can crete your own, almost oneliner inside your test suite.

```scala
implicit class ShouldDeltaEqaulsOps(val d: Double) extends AnyVal {
  def shouldIntervalEqual(d1: Double)(eps: range): Unit := {
    // range check
    d1 + eps > d && d > d1 - eps shouldBe true. 
  }
}
```